# How can I add several objects in the cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

```
 $.cookie("matrizTela", null);

 objCookie = {};

  for(var i = 1; i<vList.length;i++){

    for(var z=0;z<vList[i].length;z++){

        listaY = vList[i][z].childNodes[0].attributes;
        listaX = vList[i][z].style;

        $.each(listaY,function(key,val){
            objCookie[val.nodeName] = val.nodeValue;

        });

        $.each(listaX,function(key,val){    
            metodo = "listaX."+val;
            propValue = eval(metodo);

            objCookie[val] = propValue;
        });

        console.log(objCookie);
              //Need now add objCookie in my cookie in list form!

    }

  };
```

**OBS:** vList is matrix of lists of the DOM Object

How can I dynamically add my `objCookie` in list form on my cookie?

**Example:**

```
$.cookie("matrizTela", ["objCookie", "objCookie","objCookie"]);
```

Answer (score 6):

A cookie can store only **String** values.

The best you can do to store an array of objects is to serialize the array and store it as a string.

```
$.cookie("matrizTela", JSON.stringify(yourObjectArray));
```

For reading it back, you can do:

```
yourObjectArray = JSON.parse($.cookie("matrizTela"));
```

Comment: even though the matrix is a matrix of lists of the DOM Object ?

Comment: @user2403131 - Yes, any valid JavaScript object can go.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON botoes.js:271
btns.(anonymous function) botoes.js:271
props.click jquery-ui.js:9977
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle